# navbar collapse not functioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just copied the code from the [bootstrap starter template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/), but the collapsed menu doesn't working!

here is my code:

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="language" content="ar"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/style.css" />

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> by My Company.<br/>
        All Rights Reserved.<br/>
        <?php echo Yii::powered(); ?>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"/>

</body>
</html>
```

the js & css files loaded successfully and there is no any error shown, so what is the problem here?

Comment: Any chance you can get a Fiddle for this up and running?

Comment: I just tested and its working fine. try <!doctype html>

Comment: @LuckyChingi didn't work for me

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: @LuckyChingi look at how the scripts tags are closed at the bottom, <script/> !!! LOL

Comment: LOL, funny.. I just copied over the HTML part, have the <head> and footer already defined.

Comment: /js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css - is this correct path to your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `script` tags are not closed in the correct form `<script></script>` as you pointed out yourself, so the browser doesn't load the second JavaScript file for Bootstrap, causing the collapsible mobile menu not to function.